# WinDbg: Colon in address, what does it mean?

Tags: x86, windbg, memory-address, memory-segmentation

I have a crash dump which shows the following exception info:

```
0:000> .ecxr
eax=00000000 ebx=00000001 ecx=000000dc edx=000032f0 esi=00000020 edi=78746341
eip=00000000 esp=00000007 ebp=00000020 iopl=0         nv up di pl nz na po cy
cs=0014  ss=0034  ds=0000  es=1000  fs=df5c  gs=0000             efl=00000001
0014:00000000 ??              ???
```

Why is the exeption address displayed as `0014:00000000`, and not just `00000000`? As far as I understand, `0014` is the code segment, but I didn't find any documentation about the syntax.

Also, is there a way to translate this syntax to a plain, absolute address?

Comment: Yes, the part before the colon is the segment and the part after is the offset (EIP, in this case).

Comment: Normally in 32-bit code, the segment base for the code segment is 0. You should proceed with that assumption unless you have evidence otherwise. So the linear address is 0. Address 0 is typically not mapped in any address space, which explains the crash. (Windbg may be able to tell you the true segment base for segment 14, if you have some reason to think that it is not 0.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `seg:off` is 100% standard notation.  It's just showing you the full CS:EIP value.

CS base is `0` unless you did something *really* weird (e.g. `retf` popping something into CS that happened to index a GDT entry with a non-zero base, if there even is one).

So the linear address is just `00000000`.  e.g. you tried to jump to a NULL function-pointer or something, or tried to `ret` when ESP was pointing at a 0 instead of your return address.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the segment is displayed at all? Usually it's not part of the displayed address.

Comment: @Paul: IDK why WinDBG decided it was a good idea.  The current CS value is already displayed separately.  Purely a UI design choice.  GDB doesn't; GDB is a portable debugger (for a variety of ISAs) that's built around a flat memory model.  IDK if WinDBG has its roots in 16-bit land where `seg:off` was actually important because the normal memory model wasn't flat.  Or if the authors had a lot of experience with 16-bit x86 so it seemed natural to show the current program-counter as seg:off.

Comment: @Paul: Or maybe it's useful for debugging kernel code that might far-jump between code segments to switch modes?  IDK if WinDBG can debug the kernel, though.

Comment: WinDbg can be used as a kernel debugger, but this was a user mode crash dump.

Comment: @Paul: Right, but I wouldn't expect it to vary its output format depending on whether you're debugging the kernel or not.  The fact that kernel debugging is one of the use cases means that printing the fault address as `cs:eip` or `cs:rip` makes some sense.  (Although the kernel would use CS base = 0 as well, so it's more just to help a kernel dev notice the CS value I guess.)